# How do I get Javascript to remember a variable that is reset in my function, yet initially defined outside of my function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm creating a game where the computer tries to guess the user's number based on user feedback like too high or too low. I'm using a binary search. The functions work properly, however, every time the buttons are pressed, the code resets to make the original list from 1 to 100 making the guess 50 instead of remembering the new list and guess defined inside my functions.

```js
var list = new Array();
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  list.push(i)
}
//console.log(list)
// List is intially an empty array (list). The 
// for loop generates integers from
// 0 to 100 and pushes them into the array.

var guess = list[Math.floor((list.length / 2))];
console.log(guess);


var toolow = function(guess) {
  while (list.includes(guess) == true) {
    list.shift()
  };
  var guess = list[Math.floor((list.length / 2) - 1)];
  console.log(list);
  console.log(guess)
}

// toolow(guess)

var toohigh = function(guess) {
  var last = parseInt(list.length);
  while (list.includes(guess) == true) {
    list.pop()
  };
  var guess = list[Math.round(list.length / 2)];
  console.log(list);
  console.log(guess)
}

// toohigh(guess)
```

```html
<h1> Guess Your Number </h1>
<button id="TooLow" onclick="toolow(guess);"> Too Low</button>
<button id="TooHigh" onclick="toohigh(guess);">Too High</button>
```

Comment: teh `var guess` inside toohigh/toolow "masks" the global var guess - i.e. it's a different variable - also having guess as the argument means you now have 3 `guess` and javascript uses `var guess` inside the function

Comment: Don't redeclare/redefine `guess` inside your guess handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your over use of the variable `guess` is causing all sorts of issues

1. no need to pass guess from onclick to the function
2. don't declare a var guess inside the functions

et voila -  your code works now

```js
var list = new Array();
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  list.push(i)
}
//console.log(list)
// List is intially an empty array (list). The 
// for loop generates integers from
// 0 to 100 and pushes them into the array.

var guess = list[Math.floor((list.length / 2))];
console.log(guess);


var toolow = function() {
  while (list.includes(guess) == true) {
    list.shift()
  };
  guess = list[Math.floor((list.length / 2) - 1)];
  console.log(list);
  console.log(guess)
}

// toolow(guess)

var toohigh = function() {
  var last = parseInt(list.length);
  while (list.includes(guess) == true) {
    list.pop()
  };
  guess = list[Math.round(list.length / 2)];
  console.log(list);
  console.log(guess)
}

// toohigh(guess)
```

```html
<h1> Guess Your Number </h1>
<button id="TooLow" onclick="toolow();"> Too Low</button>
<button id="TooHigh" onclick="toohigh();">Too High</button>
```